# How can I get the relation between two categorical variables, in percentage?

Tags: pandas, crosstab

I have this dataframe:

```
id        product_type        color
A11       A                   blue
B11       B                   blue
C11       A                   red
D11       C                   red
E11       C                   black
F11       C                   red
G11       A                   black
H11       A                   red
```

And I'm trying to get the percentage of each color in each product type.

I would expect something like this:

```
product_type       black        blue       red
A                  0.25         0.25       0.50
B                  0.00         1.00       0.00
C                  0.33         0.00       0.67
```

I tried two thing, first:

```
gr = df.groupby(["product_type", "color"]).size()
(gr / gr.groupby(level=0).sum())
```

It actually worked, but I think the output is not very readable. So I decided to try this:

```
pd.crosstab(df.product_type, df.color)
```

But then I got this other error:

```
TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

So I'm kind of stuck in here...

Comment: What is your pandas version?

Answer (score 1):

For me working nice [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with `normalize` parameter:

```
df = pd.crosstab(df.product_type, df.color, normalize=0)
print (df)
color            black  blue       red
product_type                          
A             0.250000  0.25  0.500000
B             0.000000  1.00  0.000000
C             0.333333  0.00  0.666667
```

Comment: So weird, I'm still getting the error. Which pandas version are you using?

Comment: @dsbr__0 - pandas `1.2.3`